# How to make ckeditor work offline

Tags: ckeditor, hta

The jqwidget "jqxEdit" works in a html application (.hta) but with several imperfections. Therefore I try ckEditor. The ck editor window and toolbar shows up fine on the "congratulations" page, but an alert with the script error "Unable to get property 'tools' of undefined or nul reference" appears.
Has someone already figured out the modifications to the scripts to make ckEdit work offline?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code that is run server side? Maybe you need to set up a local http server (for example using XAMPP).